# A weird compiler error for c++ templates on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, templates, freebsd

```
I have the following:

class obj
{

    template<typename T>
    inline int foo(T val) const;
};


template<typename T>
int obj::foo(T val)  const
{
    //Do something for PODs
}

template<>
int obj::foo<std::vector<bool>::reference>(std::vector<bool>::reference val) const
{
    //Do something for a boolean in vector of booleans.
}

template<>
int obj::foo<std::string>(std::string var) const
{
    //Do something for string. 
}
```

When compiling with g++ for FreeBSD, the compiler complains:

`In function int obj::foo<std::_Bit_reference>(std::_Bit_reference) const':
/path/to/file.h:22: multiple definition of int obj::foo<std::_Bit_reference>(std::_Bit_reference) const'
/path/to/file.h:22 first defined here`

And the same for std::string:

`In function int obj::foo<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) const':`
etc. etc.

I can't figure out what the problem here is. Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those:

```
template<>
int obj::foo<std::vector<bool>::reference>(std::vector<bool>::reference val) const
{
    //Do something for a boolean in vector of booleans.
}

template<>
int obj::foo<std::string>(std::string var) const
{
    //Do something for string. 
}
```

are specializations and thus function definitions which should be in a .cpp (but keep a declaration in the header) and not in an header.  Having them in an header leads to have one definition in each .cpp which includes the header.

Comment: When moving the **definition** to the .cpp file, I'd recommend to consider leaving a **declaration** for each type in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the semicolon at the end of `int obj::foo(T val) const;`

Comment: I took a quick glance at your original code and thought that the problem was that `int obj::foo(T val) const;` was been treated as a redeclaration of the function, but apparently there is something else going on here as well. Whoops.